# Relative velocity between 2 frames of reference

Tags: special-relativity

In special relativity formulas for changing coordinates x,t into x',t' are based on the relative velocity of the 2 frames. What is the base for assuming that if v is the velocity of frame O' relative to frame O, the velocity of O measured by somebody on O' will be -v?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Also, I believe what you ask, at least in this form, does not need to be thought in the realm of _special relativity_ -- it seems more like a fundamental one on reference frame translations.

Comment: When i read the derivation of x&t as functions of x'&t' , then they say for the inverse we need to replace v' for v, because if O' moves r.t.O with speed v then O is moving r.t O' with -v. It is clear they assume that. But why?